# Java - User input using Scanner not working with a string

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am trying to ask the user for a simple 'yes' or 'no' response using:

```
Scanner user = new Scanner( System.in );

String response = user.nextLine();
```

I am then using the value of 'response' in a series of IF statements to output a specific piece of text.

However every time I enter in a response the program just terminates and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here's all of the code to make things more clear:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class vedant {

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    System.out.println("Is it past 11.30pm?");
    Scanner user = new Scanner( System.in );
    String response = user.nextLine();
    if (response == "yes") {
        System.out.println("tut tut tut...");
        user.close();
    } else if (response == "no") {
        System.out.println("Good boy");
        user.close();
    }
}
```

}

BTW I'm new to Java so sorry if this is quite a basic mistake.

Comment: In other words, your Scanner works fine